# "Denormalize" Sql row with 1 csv column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a table with somthing like this.

```
     Column1                              Column2

     Salade, Tomato,                       FOOD
     Earth, Water, Fire                   Element
```

I want to have a view that looks like this.

```
   Column1                Column2
  Salade                   FOOD
  Tomato                   FOOD
  Earth                    Element
  Water                    ELEMENT
```

Currently I have made a work arround with a cursor that loops true this table.
Inserts in another table...

Would this be posible without a cursor?
In 1 select statement without creating another table.

Comment: Why do you have a table like that?

Comment: Also, what version, what have you tried so far, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to use of `XML` node method to split your comma separated data

```
SELECT LTRIM(a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')) Column1, Column2
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<m>'+REPLACE([Column1], ',', '</m><m>')+'</m>' AS XML) AS [Column1],
           [Column2] FROM <table>
) m CROSS APPLY Column1.nodes('/m') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
Column1 Column2
Salade  FOOD
Tomato  FOOD
Earth   Element
Water   Element
Fire    Element
```

Comment: Very complicated